# Getting user by primary key in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working with flask and have a html page that contains of user name(user.html) which took from table, Now How can I see more detail by clicking on each of users(which route to profile)?
I don't use login for app So I don't want to use g

> app.py

```
# am I doing it right?
    @app.route('/profile/<int:id>')
    def profile(id=None):
     detail = Contacts.query.get(id)
      return render_template('profile.html', detail= detail , id=id)
```

> user.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
     <h2>show user</h2>
         {% for contact in contact  %}

          # I got error when I click on each user name to see their 'profile' 
          #I guess because of id  How can Solve it?
          #error BuildError: ('profile', {}, None)
          <strong>name:</strong><a href={{url_for('profile')}}>
            {{ contact.name}}</a><br>

           {% endfor %}
       {% endblock %}
```

> profile.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
     <h2>show user profile</h2>
     # how can I make it specific for each row of table(each user)?
         {% for detail in Contacts  %}
           <strong>name:</strong> {{ detail.name}} <br>
           <strong>email:</strong> {{ detail.email }} <br>
           <strong>age:</strong> {{ detail.age}} <br>
           <br>
           {% endfor %}

  {% endblock %}
```

> model.py

```
class Contacts(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = "Contacts"
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(50))
   email = db.Column(db.String(50))
   age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two things in your code:

```
# this
<a href={{url_for('profile')}}>

# should be
<a href={{url_for('profile', id=contact.id)}}>

# otherwise Flask can't find the route, because it needs an id
```

And the other one:

```
{% for detail in Contacts  %}
```

There is no such thing as a `Contacts` variable in your template, because your view function does not send it. Just get rid of the loop and use `detail` directly, because it's what you sent to the template.

Comment: @Linda yeah sorry about that. I updated my answer to take this in consideration. Hope it helps.